# Find the issue between the webservice and android

Tags: c#, android, web-services, debugging, arabic

I have a webservice that was built using C#.net and published online

There is an application that was built on Android that uses this service

Everything works fine except for non-latin chars (Arabic), it shows as ?????????

I have tried to test both and I noticed that the android app is sending the arabic text correctly in the XML sent to the service and tested the webservice separatly and found it reads arabic text correctly

I tried to replace the webservice with my local version of it so I can debug it
http://localhost:55000/LocServ/

but I got server is not responding

Any idea where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are saying the xml sent is correct and  separately the verified the web service reads it correctly but then where are you seeing the '???????' characters at? Also what kind of web service is this?

Comment: the text in the XML is arabic and when I test the service in the development environment it is working fine. i am not sure where in between these 2 processes the text get messed up

Comment: I would suggest that the production webservice expects a different character encoding from what the android application provides. Take a look at the character-encoding tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info